# Restful services reliabilty

Tags: java, rest, session-state

I am developing Restful services where we will be inserting/updating new records into database.

Since REST uses HTTP for its communication and HTTP is not reliable, I am worried that, the request may not be sent to the server in case of connection failure.

One of the suggestions I found in the [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/619721/Web-Services/java/REST-webservice-Message-reliability-guarantee) was "if connection fails just retry again from the client side." But we don't have any control over the client applications.

Other solution was to implement messaging systems like RabbitMQ/JMS to ensure reliability.

I also found in the following [link](https://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/building_scalable_reliable_and_secure) that adding session states improves reliability. I am not able to understand how this happen and more importantly doesn't a good restful service is always stateless?

So to summarize my questions:

1. To achieve reliability, is Messaging systems best possible approach?
2. How does session management help me in achieving reliability?

Comment: If you do not have any control over the client, there isn't much you can do.
From the server side you should try to use proper statuscodes ([see this link](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)) so the client can detect if a request gave the expected result, but even this would require the client to take note of the returned status codes and to handle them in the right way.

Comment: @Jasper Thanks for the reply. Will need to come up with the new design now and for client application to handle the requests. :)

Answer (score 1):

Messaging can help, as long as you don't do any processing when you receive a command to insert or update information, as you need to immediately put the command in a queue. This solution usually adds quite a bit of complexity as you need to notify your client asynchronously when you finish processing the command (was it successful or did it fail?... or did I fail to send the outcome?).

Session management? For reliability? Never heard of that :). Restful services are usually stateless... so no sessions here!

Another option (but depends how your clients integrate with you) is to allow your clients to generate the ids of the items you are going to be storing/updating, in this case, if they get an error back, but you have processed the command successfully, the client can retry, and the same update will happen. You can pair this with versioning to prevent stale updates arriving late.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The client id approach seems like the best option I have right now, but have to look how to integrate with the client application.